# Opel Vivaro not starting after reversed jumped cables attached

Tags: starting, starter, opel, jump-start, no-crank-no-start

just the other day i inadvertently reversed the polarity when attaching jump cables to my opel vivaro van, it was 6am and i was working with a torch and didnt realise until i hooked the live up on the car i was using to jump my van, it was only attached for a fraction of a second, now everything in my van works but the starter motor isnt engaging, i have checked what fuses i know about, there are some in the engine bay under the coolant expansion tank, and some by the drivers side window on the side of the dashboard, all seem ok, my question is are there any other situations where there might be a specific fuse for the starter motor, or could it be something else bearing in mind everything else works ok.
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you fry the ecu? , does the starter relay click and the starter solenoid engage when you crank?

Answer (score 0):

As the vans battery was still connected the damage is usually isolated to fuses.

Have you checked the fuses on top of the battery under the red cover? There's 6 fuses 3 large and 3 smaller. One or more of the 3 larger fuses are more than likely blown, most likely the 3rd one down fuse C which is a 500A fuses for the starter motor. But you should obviously check all 6.

The 3 large fuses can sometimes look ok when they are not so double check with a test light or multimeter.

According to the wiring diagram the starter solenoid connects directly to the ignition switch and not through a relay, so because everything else works the feed to the ignition switch should be there.

If all fuses are ok you should then check the main live directly the starter and then the signal wire that goes to the starter solenoid.